# How to put constants in React components, wrapped in recompose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static

How do you write a component specific constant, STATUS, that you can set `this.state.status`? I think the problem is the this context. If the `this.STATUS` is hardcoded in strings, it works.

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {
    static propTypes = {};

    // can you put the STATUS constant on the component?
    static STATUS = {
        SENT: 'SENT',
        ERROR: 'ERROR',
    };

    state = { status: null };

    // functions cannot use this.STATUS
    f = () => {
        this.setState({status: this.STATUS.SENT});
        // undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.STATUS.SENT')
    }

    render() {
        const { msg } = this.statusMessage();
        return ();
    }

}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(() => ())
)(TestComponent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `STATUS` is a [static property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods) of the class, you have to access it as follows:

```
this.constructor.STATUS.SENT
```

You can access it via `this.status` if you declare it as a property of the instance:

```
STATUS = {
  SENT: 'SENT',
  ERROR: 'ERROR',
};
```

or via a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
get STATUS() {
  return {
    SENT: 'SENT',
    ERROR: 'ERROR'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't set directly `SENT` and `Error` into your state ?

Like this :

```
this.setState({
 SEND: 'SENT'
 ERROR: 'ERROR'
 status: null
});
```

And after you set your status directly like this :

```
f = () => {
    const { SENT } = this.state
    this.setState({status: SENT});
}
```

Cheers